# Getting A Bot To Delete A User-Typed Message (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this code written down, and the bot will detect the bad word, and say "LANGUAGE!" but won't delete the message the user sent.

```
 if (badWords.some(word => msg.content.includes(word))) {
    msg.delete(1000)
    msg.reply("LANGUAGE, YOU MUFFIN!!")
  }
})
```

Comment: JavaScript and Java are very different languages. Please choose one.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: What version of DJS are you using? v12 `Message#delete()` uses a timeout option

Comment: A few days ago I wrote a [`npm package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chat-censoring) for this. Feel free to use it for your bot. I think this will fix ur problem

Answer (score 0):

```
//Replace these words with the bad words 

const word = ['shrex','fiona', 'rick astley']
        
       
    for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word[i])) {
            message.delete()
            message.reply("You muffin.")//Change this to whatever you want it to say
        }
    }
```